# How can I overcome "Failed to load model class 'VBoxModel' from module @jupyter-widgets/controls" error?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, huggingface

I am stuck at perhaps a very simple problem but I've searched the internet to no avail.

I am attempting to run the following lines in a jupyter notebook (its connected to a rented GPU):

```
# Hugging Face Login
from huggingface_hub import notebook_login

notebook_login()
```

and I keep receiving this error:

> [Open Browser Console for more detailed log - Double click to close
> this message] Failed to load model class 'VBoxModel' from module
> '@jupyter-widgets/controls' Error: Module @jupyter-widgets/controls,
> version ^1.5.0 is not registered, however,         2.0.0 is
> at f.loadClass (https://uaxtfom41wgmr3-8888.proxy.runpod.net/lab/extensions/@jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager/static/134.40eaa5b8e976096d50b2.js?v=40eaa5b8e976096d50b2:1:74977)
> at f.loadModelClass (https://uaxtfom41wgmr3-8888.proxy.runpod.net/lab/extensions/@jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager/static/150.b0e841b75317744a7595.js?v=b0e841b75317744a7595:1:10729)
> at f._make_model (https://uaxtfom41wgmr3-8888.proxy.runpod.net/lab/extensions/@jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager/static/150.b0e841b75317744a7595.js?v=b0e841b75317744a7595:1:7517)
> at f.new_model (https://uaxtfom41wgmr3-8888.proxy.runpod.net/lab/extensions/@jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager/static/150.b0e841b75317744a7595.js?v=b0e841b75317744a7595:1:5137)
> at f.handle_comm_open (https://uaxtfom41wgmr3-8888.proxy.runpod.net/lab/extensions/@jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager/static/150.b0e841b75317744a7595.js?v=b0e841b75317744a7595:1:3894)
> at _handleCommOpen (https://uaxtfom41wgmr3-8888.proxy.runpod.net/lab/extensions/@jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager/static/134.40eaa5b8e976096d50b2.js?v=40eaa5b8e976096d50b2:1:73393)
> at b._handleCommOpen (https://uaxtfom41wgmr3-8888.proxy.runpod.net/static/lab/jlab_core.4566032f8b9a1bbebc97.js?v=4566032f8b9a1bbebc97:2:1001335)
> at async b._handleMessage (https://uaxtfom41wgmr3-8888.proxy.runpod.net/static/lab/jlab_core.4566032f8b9a1bbebc97.js?v=4566032f8b9a1bbebc97:2:1003325)